# Install file conditionally through msi (Internal Error 2732)

Tags: installation, windows-installer, wise

I want to install a plugins dll to a pre-installed application. Pre-installed application has its installed location in registry from where I can get its location. If I cannot found the registry. I simply don't want to install the plugin file. I am using Wise Installation express 7.4.0.214.

What I have done is put a System search on the registry and I get the installed location of program for which I want to ship the plugin

I have created a entry in Directory table by name "PluginDir" whoes Directory_parent is set to "" and DefaultDir to "."

In MSI script I have wriiten the script on Execute Immediate tab

```
REM Display the message fetched from the registry 
Display Message [InstalledDir]  

Set Directory PluginDir to [InstalledDir]Plugin\
```

The message box show the correct fetched path but as soon as it cone to Set directory it shows “Internal Error 2732. 0”

But when I comment set directory Msi run withot error. I am not getting what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution from

http://www.dawnstar.com.au/wpshelp/tnt/conditional_changes.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid I don't know wise very well ( it's an end of life product btw )  but in MSI you put a condition on your component.  AppSearch will read the registry to try to set the property and you use the property in both assigning your directory and gating whether the component and it's file gets installed.

Answer (score 0):

Your set directory call is sequenced incorrectly.
You should sequence it after CostInitialize.

Take a look at the doc http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372835(VS.85).aspx.